# C# Reuse IEnumerator Without implement IEnumerator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this case , it trigger GC every frame.

I know IEnumerator is [Syntactic sugar](https://sharplab.io/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AwgPYA2lqAxsmORCMQOKoSoBOYtO2AB2AAjSrxi1KAQxAgYpGAG9sMVTACSAUQjB03KcnJcAPMPJUAfDE0APKegE0AYsAj1GEABQBKFWuVqgfDkeqTSsjAAFqhSAG4IAPLCAFZ0yDAAvDCcAO7BoeEgPjhBajmRYDSe0XGJKWnEAApc5LSosj6+paoB3YEIYKiUACYwXKjIwFwQMMhcwKgl3QC+2H6lYABmngCENfFJqfTEcMC0bbJd3b19qgNDo+OT0zCbUpQgi+tBq9+BAPT/DQzZAVOSoOwOGgAGhgOVQAHJqNlULFuDAoBMotxUDAALRwyIGKJSAQCDhyQyzaIwSC0EKOCa47S6fSGLh/NSAmAAdWiM2G5Ha2NqhzSGKxrFICOGAH5Oap9nUjshiAARchwEKoACyRlQcEmm223iWqlWvyEonEkhkci1BTtSm+VrEtBgZioMGarXaRW8zr6TymIPmX0Cq0CLpEbo95ko8DOFxAZpg0et7ti5DAow1Dt1+sNwGNPiUFuwQAAA==) , when yield a IEnumerator function , it will create a new object. Have any way to keep IEnumrator and reuse that !?
And I don't want to implement IEnumerator directly, because it more complex.

```
[ContextMenu("CoroutineGCTest2")]
public void CoroutineGCTest2()
{
    Debug.LogFormat("[CoroutineMemoryTest.CoroutineGCTest2]");
    StartCoroutine(GCTest());
}

struct ForGC
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
}

IEnumerator GCTest()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return GC(new ForGC());
    }
}

IEnumerator GC(ForGC g)
{
    yield return null;
}
```

**WaitForSecondsRealtime Reuse way by implement IEnumerator**

```
IEnumerator GCTest()
{
    //cache it
    WaitForSecondsRealtime wait = new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1f); ;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return wait;
        Debug.LogFormat("wait 1 sec");
        wait.Reuse(2f);
        yield return wait;
        Debug.LogFormat("wait 2 sec");
        //yield return GC();
    }
}

public class WaitForSecondsRealtime : CustomYieldInstruction
{
    public float waitTime { get; set; }
    float m_WaitUntilTime = -1;

    public override bool keepWaiting
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_WaitUntilTime < 0)
            {
                m_WaitUntilTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + waitTime;
            }

            bool wait = Time.realtimeSinceStartup < m_WaitUntilTime;
            if (!wait)
            {
                // Reset so it can be reused.
                m_WaitUntilTime = -1;
            }
            return wait;
        }
    }

    public WaitForSecondsRealtime(float time)
    {
        waitTime = time;
    }

    public void Reuse(float time)
    {
        m_WaitUntilTime = -1;
        waitTime = time;
    }
}
```

But it more compplex..

Comment: `IEnumerator is Syntactic sugar` what do you mean? And what do you mean by `reuse that`? The IEnumerator? or the ForGC object you created?

Comment: It will create a new ForGC object but not necessarily trigger the GC until necessary (or manually triggered). You can use struct so it is on the stack but it looks like you are trying to fix a problem that may not exist.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#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

Comment: IEnumerator Complier to a Class , When yield mean It new class once , I want to avoid that , I have no ideal so maybe have some way to fix !?

Comment: Create a `private WaitForEndOfFrame endOfFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame()` then simply yield return endOfFrame. I personnaly use a class Yielders with static variables that I use in my project.

Comment: @Jichael It is usefull !! , But when IEnumrator have paramters & dynamic set paramters  , I dont know how to do !?

Comment: I don't really understand WHY you'd need that. You use a coroutine to yield for a frame or a fixed amount of time, else you should use something else IMO

Comment: @Jichael what about `yield return new WaitForseconds(value)` with a dynamic value? ;) However .. @TimChang .. this having a new "IEnumerator instance" created has so minimal influence on effiency etc that you really don't have to care about it

Comment: @derHugo In my project I use 3 variables in my Yielders class WaitForSeconds called oneSecond, pointFiveSecond, and pointOneSecond, and I mix them. I never had a use case when I needed a really precise dynamic value

Comment: @derHugo yes for waitforsceonds(value) is really small scope , Im care about a custom IEnumerator that have more local variable and paramter , it mean more cost to new a IEnumerator ,sorry, this question is not explained well..

Comment: Well I had ;) I'm just saying it is a bit dangerous to generalize things to much. If there would never be a use case of having dynamic values for `WaitForSecond` then it would maybe have been implemented differently

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse an IEnumerator function. It is one-way, one-use object. IEnumerator has `Reset` function but it cannot be used in this case.

```
IEnumerator GCTest()
{
    // An attempt to cache and reuse IEnumerator function
    var e = GC(new ForGC());
    while (true)
    {
        yield return e;
        e.Reset( ); // System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
    }
}
```

So what now?

- Refactor your GC() function that it can do work without having to be IEnumerator function. Eliminating the need of IEnumerator and need of `yield return`.

  - There must be some alternative implementation without using IEnumerator, such as using `Update` cycle, state and timer to achieve the same code effect.
  - Actually IEnumerator function also got break down internally by compiler magic to do exactly like that. (as OP has posted a link on first line)
- Create an object that implement IEnumerator to do the work. (That OP said it is complex)
- Alternatively use newer framework that could run coroutine in more light-weighted way. See https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx on the section **MicroCoroutine**.